# How can I increase the number of decimal digits when converting BigDecimal to String?

Tags: ruby

I am facing a problem with BigDecimal.

This code:

```
x = BigDecimal.new('1.0') / 7
puts x.to_s
```

outputs:

```
0.142857142857142857E0
```

I want to increase the number of digits.

In JAVA, I could do:

```
BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal("1");
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("7");

n = n.divide(d,200, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

System.out.println(n);
```

The output is:

```
0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428... (200 digits)
```

I looked at [BigDecimal documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html), and tried to set the digits when instantiating the number, then tried to set the limit with the BigDecimal.limit, but I couldn't  print more than 18 digits.

What am I missing?

I am running ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32] on Windows 7 64bits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `div` method allows you to specify the digits:

```
x = BigDecimal.new('1.0').div( 7, 50 )
puts x
```

With a result of:

```
0.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714E0
```

Comment: This is the only way (as of now) to make this work. According to the docs, BigDecimal.limit(x) should achieve the same effect, but due to a bug (https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8826) it won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the internal representation of a big decimal, the to_s method is responsible for converting it to a string. I see to_s supports a format string:

```
Converts the value to a string.

The default format looks like 0.xxxxEnn.

The optional parameter s consists of either an integer; or an optional ‘+’ or ‘ ’, followed by an optional number, followed by an optional ‘E’ or ‘F’.

If there is a ‘+’ at the start of s, positive values are returned with a leading ‘+’.

A space at the start of s returns positive values with a leading space.

If s contains a number, a space is inserted after each group of that many fractional digits.

If s ends with an ‘E’, engineering notation (0.xxxxEnn) is used.

If s ends with an ‘F’, conventional floating point notation is used.

Examples:

BigDecimal.new('-123.45678901234567890').to_s('5F') -> '-123.45678 90123 45678 9'

BigDecimal.new('123.45678901234567890').to_s('+8F') -> '+123.45678901 23456789'

BigDecimal.new('123.45678901234567890').to_s(' F') -> ' 123.4567890123456789'
```

Comment: you didn't answer my question.